# jinja2-cli how to get env variable into the template

Tags: yaml, jinja2, jinja2-cli

I have a jinja template defined as deployment.yml.j2 with

```yml
environments:
  default:
    databricks_host: data
    jobs:
      - test: "{% lookup('env', 'ENVIRONMENT_TYPE') %}"
```

The variable file does not matter, it can be an empty file.
When parsing the template and file with `jinja2 --format=yml deployment.yml.j2 conf_staging.yml` I get `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'lookup' is undefined`
I also tried to get the system env vars with env['ENVIRONMENT_TYPE']. In python, this works but from the CLI, I get that env is undefined.
Any help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: From what I know, lookup is an Ansible addition to Jinja, are you sure you did not load specific Jinja plugin in your Python script?

Comment: Just to confirm what @β.εηοιτ.βε said, `lookup` is an Ansible-specific function. The list of built-in Jinja functions, filters, and tests can be found [the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/). If it's not there, it doesn't exist unless you explicitly add custom functions to your Jinja environment. It looks like `jinja2-cli` has a `--extension` option for loading [custom extensions](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/extensions/).

Comment: I did not add any extensions. Can I do something like env['ENVIRONMENT_TYPE'] besides the lookup? This is how I have it defined in the template and the dbx can parse it properly. Now I also try to get some job-specific details in the ci/cd so I need to parse it in the cli.

Comment: Then I guess your best bet is to pass the environment variable to the cli, something like `echo "{\"ENVIRONMENT_TYPE\", \"$ENVIRONMENT_TYPE\"}" | jinja2-cli template.j2`